# GET ALL VALUES INNER JOIN MYSQL

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, outer-join

I have a simple question, I wonder how do you do this....

Let's say

```
Table 1 I have userId and name (1000 records)
Table 2 I have carId and name (90 records)
Table 3 I have userId, carId and value (820 records)
```

There's simple join that would let me accomplish what I wanted like

```
select * from table3 A 
inner join table1 B on A.userId=B.userId 
inner join table2 C on A.carId=C.carId;
```

However there's a case where if a user doesn't own a specific type of car, the value should be set to 0 instead of not showing in the count.

to make things simple

i have 3(0-2) users and 2 (0-1) car manufacturer,
the data that I want is probably like this,

current data generated from the query above:

```
0,1,200
1,0,100
1,1,100
```

while I wanted it to be like this ( to include those that have no records but set a default value to 0 if there is no record)

```
id,car,val
0,0,0
0,1,200
1,0,100
1,1,100
2,0,0
2,1,0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this: The key is using left outer join, instead of inner join. Inner join requires there to be a row in both the joined tables. left join only requires a row in the first (left-hand) table specified. Then you can use a "coalesce" statement to display 0 instead of null for the empty rows.

```
select
  u.userId,
  coalesce(c.carId, 0),
  coalesce(uc.value, 0)
from
  table1 u
  left outer join table3 uc on u.userId = uc.userId
  left outer join table2 c on uc.carId = c.carId
```

Comment: thanks for the idea, but that would assume that every user without any record in table3 will automatically get a 0 in carId. while what makes sense is x-user iterating through y-cars with value 0 if no record and n if there is any?

Comment: @kenlz that's what you asked for: "if a user doesn't own a specific type of car, the value should be set to 0". So for every user, if they don't have that car, the value for carID will be given as 0, exactly as you requested. If they have the car, it will give the correct carID. That's what COALESCE does - it looks at the first parameter (carID in this case), and if it's null, it displays the second parameter (0 in this case). If the first parameter isn't null, it displays the first parameter.

Comment: i was referring to the column value actually, so i guess it was a miscommunication. is there a way to actually re-iterate the whole y-carIds and set the value 0 if there is none? thanks!

Comment: @kenlz I'm not sure what you mean. coalesce will set the value of that column to 0 in the result. And it will show all possible cars for all possible users, with 0 where that user does not have the car. If that's not what you want please be clearer about your exact requirements. I don't understand what "re-iterate the whole y-carIds" means, if it doesn't mean what I've just said above. Have you run my query to see if it produces a suitable result? It's possible I may have made a mistake, if so it would be useful to see the actual vs expected result. (I don't have your data so I can't do it)

Comment: say I have 3 type of carIds (0:Sedan, 1: Truck, 2: SUV) and I have 1k users, so I will need to check whether user A own a carId 101,102 or 103. eventually I'd have 1k * 3 = 3000 records. While my table 3 currently holds 850 records, so I will need to check 850 records whether each user own each cars. if they own a car, it should have a value, if they dont then the value should be 0 (carId should not be 0 because we are checking the value for user to carId) I hope this clears it out. Thanks @Adyson

Comment: @kenlz so if they don't own the car, carID should be null, but the "value" column should be 0?

Comment: if they dont own a car, it should contain 3 rows like user A with cardId 101,102,103 and their value are all set to 0